# How to access url from dict structure of a json url

Tags: python, json, csv, request

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url)

data = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode()
```

Once i get the aws site string i can load it up in python, but how do i catch it?

The .json is actually a website with below structure. The aws website is a csv when you open it.

Is there a library within json which can help with this?

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbEQg.png)

Comment: Json file is a dictionary? So treat it like so. After using read()

Answer (score 0):

You can get URL like this:

```
import json
data = json.load(file object)
url = data.get('export').get('url')
```

If it is a string use:

```
json.loads(string)
```

If it is a json file use:

```
json.load(file object)
```

[More Information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)